# Is it safe to use my phone while charging it? Does a charger leak electricity?

Tags: charger, mobile

My cousins always tell me that it is not safe to use or call someone on a mobile phone while charging it.
Is this just a myth or is this true?
I read somewhere that most phone chargers are isolated(what does isolation mean?)
Please explain in simple terms. I would like to know more.

Comment: Old phones would heat up when drawing excess power and being charged up at the same time and some have exploded. the isolation is safe but you might get a tingle or burn feeling touching ground with your wrist, from the SMPS Noise feedthru.

Comment: It has been safe ever since my first got a smartphone in 2012. There is no problem with it. Isolated means it has been designed so if something fails in the wall adapter, the high voltage from the wall won't be able to blast through and make it to the phone to shock you.

Comment: No electrical device is 100% safe. But it depends if your cousin means safety to the person or safety to the phone. Batteries and chargers can get damaged so that they are not safe. If you drop your phone and the battery gets damaged, it could explode thus it is safer to not use your phone while charging. Or if it is a metallic phone and you have a cheap sub-standard charger that develops a fault in the isolation and connects phone to mains when it is in your hand. These are extreme examples, but in general, usually if everything works then it is quite safe to use while charging.

Comment: ElectroBOOM just released a video debunking (rectifying!) a nonsense video about how it is unsafe to hold your phone while charging. See here: https://youtu.be/iX1Myc51Pvc?t=207  The old man in the video uses a **very sensitive tester** that will light up/beep when even a small AC current flows. This AC current is **perfectly safe** as it is **too small** to do anything harmful. Learn from **real electrical engineers** like ElectroBOOM instead of old guys that have **no clue** on Youtube.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why someone downvoted the question since it's appropriate and useful.

*In theory* when you are charging the phone there's only about 5V involving from the power supply and the charger itself is build to avoid the mains reaching your phone.

That's the theory and in 99% of the cases it's correct. However, low quality chargers abound and not all of these have good insulation. In fact there have been casualties from people phoning in the bathtub with the charger attached.

So, if you are not excessively wet and the charger is well build the risk of shock is about the same of lifting a powered television set (i.e. substantially none)

Comment: DV probably because questions about the use of electronic devices are off topic.

Comment: Your answer seems to be: most of the time it's safe...except that there have been casualties...and there are lots of unsafe chargers out there...just make sure you are only a little wet...verify that your charger is well built before trying this at home.